# PyKrige witing a file with 3D kriged data

Tags: interpolation, kriging, geostatistics

I am trying to krig soil volumes in 3D using pykrige. I am using ordinary kriging, but once I am done kriging the data, I am not sure how I can write it to an ascii file, Here is my code:

```
from pykrige.ok3d import OrdinaryKriging3D
from pykrige.uk3d import UniversalKriging3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt

data_in = pd.read_excel("Krig3D_data.xlsx")
data = data_in.to_numpy()

gridx = np.arange(392050, 392250, 5)
gridy = np.arange(5138395, 5138595,5)
gridz = np.arange(0.0, 5, 0.25)
                     
ok3d = OrdinaryKriging3D(
    data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], data[:, 3], variogram_model="linear"
)

k3d1, ss3d = ok3d.execute("grid", gridx, gridy, gridz)
```

I need to export the kriged data in an ascii file so I can visualize it by slices elsewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian here from the [GeoStat-Framework](https://github.com/GeoStat-Framework) Team. If you want to also save the kriged data by slices (like you want to plot them later), you could add the following lines of code:

```py
for i, z in enumerate(gridz):
    kt.write_asc_grid(
        gridx, gridy, k3d1[:, :, i], filename="output_z{:.1}.asc".format(z)
    )
```

Note, that the corresponding z-value is added to the file-name with one decimal place.